# How to fix the overseer/queue exception KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /overseer/queue

Tags: solr, apache-zookeeper, solrcloud

After restarting both the SOLR and Zookeeper I am getting this error "KeeperException$ConnectionLossException: KeeperErrorCode = ConnectionLoss for /overseer/queue" in the SOLR logs and my SOLR is lagging and not working as expected

I tried deleting the /overseer/queue from the Zookeeper and again restarting it. It worked but I still want to know the reason why does this happen.